# find the initial message from the response email

Tags: php, email

I want to do the following,say, from the email address notifications@example.com I send an email to john@gmail.com (or to any other email service) with the subject "Hello" then, when the John clicks reply and sends the response message, is there a way to find out that the received email from john@gmail.com was the reply of my EXACT(because it is possible that there are many emails received from John with the same subject) email with the subject "Hello".

The idea is the following. user1 and user2 are registered on my website. user1 sends a message to user2. I am sending a notification to user2 - saying that user1 sent you a message, you can answer to this email - and it will be sent to user1 on your behalf from the registered website.

I thought is there a way to send some header information or smth else, that will be unique and will be returned in the response email, so I can check it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing only with Gmail, the Gmail servers generate a message ID per email that is used to track replies. Specifically, you can examine the `Message-ID`, `References`, and `In-Reply-To` header elements in the email.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1345526/549346 for some relevant details.

Some versions of Exchange do very similar things as well. So, as usual, the answer is "it depends."