# how to use getInReplyTo()?

Tags: java, email, imap

I am trying to get information about the mail to which a particular mail has replied...
I am using getInReplyTo() function of imap but I don't know how to use it as I am begginer....
This is my code:

```
 MimeMessage msg = (MimeMessage) messages[i];
String replyto = msg.getInReplyTo();
          System.out.println(replyto);
```

but it gives error:

```
test2.java:129: error: cannot find symbol
           String replyto = msg.getInReplyTo();
                               ^


 symbol:   method getInReplyTo()
  location: variable msg of type MimeMessage
```

What am i doing wrong??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345513/can-i-track-an-imap-mail-reply

Comment: getInReplyTo() is your method?

Comment: What is the `msg` type?? can you show us its class code??

Comment: @JavaLearner:I saw that but there is no hint how to use it..it would be great if you could help me with that..

Comment: no..its a method of imapmessage class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain about the error, it says there there is no method `getInReplyTo()` available in `MimeMessage` Class definition. To solve your problem, You are using `MimeMessage` type instead of `IMAPMessage` type. Change the type of `msg` variable to type `IMAPMessage`.

Note : You are doing the typecase to `MimeMessage` and then invoking the `IMAPMessage` 's method. You  can't do that.

Comment: you mean to say that I should make message to be of type imapmessage instead of mime message?